# Circular dependency when Lazy Loading between BL and BE

Tags: c#, oop, lazy-loading

I have basically a business layer, a business entities and a data access (SQL) layer.

The business entities layer is referenced by business layer and data access layer.

I've made a test to set lazyloading in which one I call function that fills entities from business layer to entity layer.

Issue: circular dependency! I can not call BL from BE because BE is used by BL

Here is the code that is interesting:

Entity properties:

```
 // Not lazyloaded properties
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        // lazy loaded properties
        private Lazy<AuditTypeEntity> _auditType = null;
        public AuditTypeEntity auditType
        {
            get
            {
                return _auditType.Value;
            }
        }
```

Entity constructor that I've made (but I can't use it because there is a circular redundancy: BL calls BE so BE can't call BL):

```
public MyEntity()
        {
        _auditType = new Lazy<AuditTypeEntity>(() => BusinessLayer.GetAuditTypeById(_auditTypeId).Value);
}
```

**EDIT:**

I'm using ADO.NET and it fills an entity object.

Here is an example on how I call my DAL layer:

```
public static IList<Nature> GetAllNature()
        {
            using (DAOManager daomanager = DAOFactory.CreateDaoManager(DataSource.DB_Belval))
            {
                return daomanager.GetNatureDAO().GetAll(BE.EnumEntity.NATURE.ANOMALY);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You shouldn't make lower layers dependent on higher levels at all, if that needs to be done then inject the way they can talk to the layer above. You've essentially coupled the two layers together making them one layer. Don't do this.

Comment: `Lazy` has nothing to do with lazy loading. It's about lazy *initialization*. What ORM are you using? Child entities are lazily loaded by default in EF.

Comment: Even if you want to create your own OMR/data layer (why?) you don't need `Lazy` to lazily load anything. Just check the field's value and load the entity if it's empty. That *shouldn't* be exposed outside the data layer though. If you have an entity whose values may not be needed in a scenario, it probably means you need two separate entities

Comment: Thanks all. I want lazy loading because my objects are very hudge with a lot of big List<> and someimes I use those fields sometimes not so this is why I want to use LazyLoading. I use ADO.NET as I mentionned on the edit after your question ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example on how you can achieve this.
As that, you can use a custom constructor in order to give Lazy dependencies.

! The DAL is the only one that should handle Lazy !

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var bll = new BLL();
        var person = bll.GetPerson();
        var orders = person.Orders; // GetOrders in DAL will be excuted here
    }
}

// BLL project
public class BLL
{
    public Person GetPerson()
    {
        return new DAL().GetPerson(1);
    }
}

// Entity Project
public class Person
{
    public Person()
    {

    }
    public Person(Lazy<IEnumerable<Order>> orders)
    {
        _orders = orders;
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    private Lazy<IEnumerable<Order>> _orders = null;

    public IEnumerable<Order> Orders
    {
        get { return _orders?.Value; }
        set { _orders = new Lazy<IEnumerable<Order>>(() => value); }
    }

}

public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

// DAL Project
public class DAL
{
    public Person GetPerson(int id)
    {
        var person = new Person(new Lazy<IEnumerable<Order>>(() => GetOrders(id))) // Init lazy
        {
            Id = id,
            Name = "Person"
        };
        return person;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Order> GetOrders(int personId)
    {
        return new List<Order> { new Order { Id = 2, Name = "Order" } };
    }
}
```

Comment: amazing! that exactly feet what I wanted. I keep lazyloading in the DAL and voilà! Many thnaks @user3608494